# OpenLayers setting position of overlay on a static image

Tags: openlayers-3

I have created a map with OpenLayers 3 using static image. It uses fake projection so the map can use to properly display the layer as it's measured in pixels. This is the code:

```
var pixelProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'pixel',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, 0, 1389, 1070]
});


var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://s25.postimg.org/4o15oqbmn/jdgf.jpg',
        imageSize: [1389, 1070],
        projection: pixelProjection,
        imageExtent: pixelProjection.getExtent()
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View2D({
    projection: pixelProjection,
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(pixelProjection.getExtent()),
    zoom: 2
  }) 
});
```

I was trying to add marker overlays to add some more interactions however I'm struggling to specify position and the markers is outside the map rather then inside where I want to place it.

```
var marker = new ol.Overlay({
    position: [200, 200],
    element: document.getElementById('marker'),
    stopEvent: false
});
```

I'm very novice to this so if anyone have an idea how to set position correctly I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Using this [OpenLayers 3 map](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/icon.html?q=marker) as an example, I was able to add a marker to the center of your static image with the following:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([700, 700])
});

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
    })
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
```